# android firebase location update every 5 minutes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to make sure that my database will get the current updated location every 5 minutes while the user is signed in..., im looking for a solution that will work with what i wrote...

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(UserProfile.this);

        double lat = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
        double lang = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("latitude").setValue(lat);
        mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("longitude").setValue(lang);
        mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Availability").setValue(true);
        mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Availability").onDisconnect().setValue(false);


    }
```

as you cant see, at the moment i get the location only after going online only and it stay static unless u exit and go  in again to the activity...
i heard about something called Handler, but i didnt managed to use it correctly(or its not ment for what im intending?)
thank you!

Comment: Nothing here reads data from the Firebase Database yet. I highly recommend reading the [Firebase documentation on retrieving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events) and taking the [Firebase codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: what (library) do you use to get the location? you can use [Fused Location Provider API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi), here's [the guide](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) then set the update interval to 60*5*1000 (5 minutes)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it dosent read anything yet, it just update the database....

Answer (score 0):

I deeply suggest you do this with Services. They are built in functions that can run in background.

And I recommend using android location listener for the location in the service.